# How to copy a Chart from Excel to Word with OpenXml SDK?

Tags: excel, charts, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an Excel file with one sheet and one chart. I am trying to copy this chart and paste it on a new Word document using OpenXml SDK. I do not want an image of the chart, but an editable chart object, not referenced to the Excel file.

This is what I tried:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("Test1.xlsx", true))
{
     var bkPart = document.WorkbookPart;
     var workbook = bkPart.Workbook;
     var s = workbook.Sheets.FirstOrDefault();
     var wsPart = bkPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();
     var dp = wsPart.DrawingsPart;
     var dWs = dp.WorksheetDrawing;
     var cp = dp.ChartParts.FirstOrDefault();
     var plotArea = cp.ChartSpace.Descendants<PlotArea>().FirstOrDefault();

     using (var docx = WordprocessingDocument.Open("Test1.docx", true))
     {
          docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.RemoveAllChildren();
          var cpw = docx.MainDocumentPart.AddPart(cp);
          var p = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph();
          var r = new Run();
          var d = new Drawing();
          var i = new Inline();
          var g = new Graphic();
          var gd = new GraphicData();
          var c = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart();

          docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(p);
          p.Append(r);
          r.Append(d);
          d.Append(i);
          i.Append(g);
          g.Append(gd);
          gd.Append(c);
          // I am stuck here
     }
}
```

I tried to take the ChartPart from Excel and adding it to the Word document and then to create a new chart referencing the inserted new ChartPart. Unfortunately, I am stuck on this step. How can I get and use this reference to create the chart? Otherwise is there another way to copy a chart from Excel to Word?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This kind of thing is so convoluted... To get a starting point, I recommend: set up a very simple "target" Word document and save it. Copy an Excel chart and paste special it into the document as a Chart object, without a link. Save this to a different name. Use the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to open the original document, then use the Compare feature on the document with the chart. This will give you the basic Open XML and the code to produce that second document from the first. You can then compare that to the chart object in the Excel file.

Comment: Basically, I *think* you'll be able to copy the chart "part" from Excel, add that to the Word document, with the necessary relationships and "framing" the Word document requires to include such an object "in-line" or "floating".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this workaround to copy a chart from Excel to Word:

1. Create a new ChartPart on the Word document.
2. Add to this ChartPart a ChartSpace cloned from Excel.
3. Add a new chart to the Word document referencing the new ChartPart.

This is the code:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("Test1.xlsx", true))
{
    var bkPart = document.WorkbookPart;
    var workbook = bkPart.Workbook;
    var s = workbook.Sheets.FirstOrDefault();
    var wsPart = bkPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();
    var dp = wsPart.DrawingsPart;
    var dWs = dp.WorksheetDrawing;
    var cp = dp.ChartParts.FirstOrDefault();
    using (var docx = WordprocessingDocument.Open("Test1.docx", true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = docx.MainDocumentPart;
        ChartPart chartPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>("rId777");
        chartPart.ChartSpace = (ChartSpace)cp.ChartSpace.Clone();

        var paragraph = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00C75AEB", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "000F3EFF" };
        Run run = new Run();
        Drawing drawing = new Drawing();
        Inline inline = new Inline();
        inline.Append(new Extent() { Cx = 5274310L, Cy = 3076575L });
        DocProperties docPros = new DocProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "Chart7" };
        inline.Append(docPros);
        Graphic g = new Graphic();
        var graphicData = new GraphicData() { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" };
        var chartReference = new ChartReference() { Id = "rId777" };
        graphicData.Append(chartReference);
        g.Append(graphicData);
        inline.Append(g);
        drawing.Append(inline);
        run.Append(drawing);
        paragraph.Append(run);
        mainPart.Document.Body.Append(paragraph);
    }
}
```